# Table view button shows up after I scroll down page one time

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to add a custom radio button to each cell in a table view.  When I first view the table view, I can't see any radio button.  But when I scroll down I can see radio buttons on each cell underneath the initial cells that are seen when the view is first loaded.  And once a cell that didn't have a radio button on it goes out of view, and I go back to view that cell, the radio button appears.

Here is my code for this one method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *ImageCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ImageCellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
_radioBtn.frame = CGRectMake(275, 3,36,36);
_radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio-Btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:_radioBtn];

NSString *cellValue = [_arrayRelat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(88.0/255.0) green:(88.0/255.0) blue:(89.0/255.0) alpha:1];

return cell;
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand the question.

Comment: i didn't understand, how you got a cell without that radio button!!! You are adding radio button to all cells. There is no condition for adding radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting _radioBtn with every new cell!
You should create a new Instance of UIButton for every cell such as:

```
UIButton *radioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
radioBtn.frame = CGRectMake(275, 3,36,36);
[radioBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio-Btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.contentView addSubview:radioBtn];
```

and you should put it inside your `if (cell == nil)` block to only create it once for each cell.

Comment: Sorry I can't up vote your answer, I just got a down vote for this question, so my score is less than 15..